# Does hip support complex types and arithmetic?

Tags: complex-numbers, hip

I'm porting some CUDA code to HIP so I can run on AMD GPUs but the code uses `cuda::std::complex`. Can I just include the standard C++ header `include <complex>`, do I need to implement my own complex operations using the regular intrinsics, or is there a HIP equivalent?